# How to configure active admin to show the users password without encryption in admin screens?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, devise, passwords, activeadmin

I have a `User` model in my `rails` application this is a `devise` Model which contains `password` field. i have `activeadmin` gem. How can we `configure` `active admin` ,So that it shows the `password` without `encryption`. Currently the application is showing the `encrypted` password in active admin screens.

Comment: I don't know anything about the "activeadmin" gem, but if it is at all decent, what you want to do is impossible.  Passwords aren't (shouldn't be) encrypted in databases, they are hashed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You'd need to disable password hashing in Devise but it's - for good reason - an integral part of [`DatabaseAuthenticable`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable).

Comment: This should be a comment.